# Powershell - if $var -like $var*

Tags: powershell

I'm working with SCSM in Powershell but running into an issue with an if statement.

I have a function that collects data based on a criteria that is passed into the function as a variable.
Example:

```
$JMLs1 = collectTickets -crit $JMLCriteria1
```

`collectTickets` is the function, `$JMLCriteria1` is the criteria that is passed.

This is the `collectTickets` function:

```
function collectTickets
{
    param (
        [parameter (Mandatory=$true)]
        $crit
    )
    $fullDate = Get-Date
    if ($fullDate.DayOfWeek -eq 'Monday') 
    {
        $olderThan = $fullDate.AddDays(-4)
    }
    elseif ($fullDate.DayOfWeek -eq 'Tuesday') 
    {
        $olderThan = $fullDate.AddDays(-4)
    }
    else 
    {
        $olderThan = $fullDate.AddDays(-2)
    }
    if ($crit -like '$JML*') 
    {
        $data = Get-SCSMObject -Criteria $crit | select 'Id', 'Title', 'LastModified', 'Priority'
    }
    else 
    {
        $data = Get-SCSMObject -Criteria $crit | Where-Object {($_.LastModified -lt $olderThan)} | select 'Id', 'Title', 'LastModified', 'Priority'
    }
    return $data
}
```

The issue I'm having is with the second if statement, the `if ($crit -like '$JML*')` - I'm not sure if we can use wildcards like this against variables or if the syntax is just not correct.

Just to clarify there will be multiple `$JML` criteria variables as well as multiple other criteria variables, but it's only the `$JML` criteria variables that I want to treat differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single. With single quotes, PowerShell thinks you are looking for the the literal string `$JML`, not the variable.

```
if ($crit -like "$JML*")
```

**Edit:** [about_Quoting documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)